# Making white vinegar, question about rice wine

Tags: vinegar, rice-wine

I'm going to start a batch of rice wine that will eventually be turned into vinegar. Is it important to age the wine for a long period for this use or can it be used after it has fermented for a few months?

Also, should I pasteurize the wine before the vinegar process or just leave that part out?

I'm making the wine only because it doesn't seem cost effective to buy it to turn it into vinegar. Store bought rice wine is twice as expensive as the vinegar itself. Is there a more cost effective way of doing this that I might be missing?

Comment: You should ask this in home brewing as well.

Comment: @Escoce please don't tell people to ask on another SE site "as well". Cross posting within the network is not allowed even when topics overlap. If this is on topic for Homebrew, we'll have to migrate, because brewing is not in our scope (see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I contacted the moderators from there first, because I am not sure if this falls in their scope. If it does not, I won't migrate.

Comment: Understood, I am a member there too, it's in scope or at least likely to be to

Comment: I know how to make the wine. I'm only unsure if it matters to age it for the purpose of making vinegar. I'm not sure a home brew group is best for practical advice on how to make vinegar but I haven't seen that group. I will check it out and join in case this gets moved.

Comment: Edited to show this is more about making vinegar than it is about making wine.

Comment: @JasonWhipple a lot of home brew goes into making vinegar which is just another stage along the life of a brew.